# Testing the convergence of the series $\sum 1/(k^q (\ln k)^p)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms

> Determine all values of $p$ and $q$ for which the following series converges:
>   $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^q (\ln k)^p}$$
>   Hints : Consider the three case $q>1$, $q=1$, $q<1$.

I understand how to find them when $q=1$. I am struggling with $q<1$ and $q>1$, hope anyone can help.

Comment: I edited your question to implement [LaTeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You might get better help if you use LaTeX whenever possible and if you use grammatically correct and sensical sentences.

Comment: $q=1$ is the only hard case… for $q>1$ and $q<1$, the log term is irrelevant (since $\ln k$ is $o(k^{\varepsilon})$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$).  So the series diverges for $q<1$ and converges for $q>1$.

Comment: hint for q=1
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227199/does-the-series-sum-n-2-infty-frac1n-lnn2-converge-or-diver?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

In these two cases you can compare the given series with $\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k^q}$ if $q>1$ and with $\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{q+\frac{1-q}{2}}}$ if $q<1$