# Does the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n(\ln(n))^{2}}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

As said above, does this series converge or diverge? Is there a certain identity/theorem to prove this?

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n(\ln(n))^{2}}$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2563446/on-convergence-of-bertrand-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-alpha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one knows the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test),
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\text{ converges } \iff
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n a_{2^n}\text{ converges}$$
one may observe that
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{2^n}{2^n(\ln(2^n))^{2}}=\frac1{\ln^2 2}\cdot\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{2}}<\infty
$$ the given series is thus *convergent*.

Comment: I was not yet taught this in school although this seems to be quite applicable in the maths I am doing. Thank you for bringing this test to my attention.

Comment: @goldenlinx You are welcome.

Answer (score 8):

Use integral test. Observe you have
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_3 \frac{dx}{x(\log x)^2} = \int^\infty_{\log 3}\frac{du}{u^2}<\infty.
\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

The convergence of this series follows from the Kraft–McMillan inequality ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraft%E2%80%93McMillan_inequality)). There is a binary prefix code for the positive integers which encodes any integer $n\ge 2$ in $\lceil \log_2 n\rceil + 2 \lceil \log_2 \log_2 n\rceil + 1$ bits, as follows:

- First, write down a sequence $11\dots1$ of length $\lceil \log_2 \log_2 n\rceil$, followed by $0$, communicating the value of $\lceil \log_2 \log_2 n\rceil$.
- Then, write down $\lceil\log_2 n\rceil$ in binary, which takes $\lceil \log_2 \log_2 n\rceil$ bits, communicating the value of $\lceil\log_2 n\rceil$. (The previous step was necessary so we'd know when to stop reading the binary value.)
- Then, write down $n$ in binary, which takes $\lceil \log_2 n\rceil$ bits. (The previous step was necessary so we'd know when to stop reading the binary value.)

Therefore, by the Kraft–McMillan inequality,
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^{-(\lceil \log_2 n\rceil + 2 \lceil \log_2 \log_2 n\rceil + 1)} \le 1.$$
But $2^{-(\lceil \log_2 n\rceil + 2 \lceil \log_2 \log_2 n\rceil + 1)} \sim \frac{1}{2n (\log_2 n)^2}$, which is only off by a constant factor from $\frac{1}{n (\ln n)^2}$, so
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n (\ln n)^2}$$ must also converge.

Comment: Thank you for bringing the Kraft–McMillan inequality to our attention ;)  (+1)

Comment: I think it's actually very closely related to why this series converges! The sequence $\sum \frac1{n^2}, \sum \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^2}, \sum \frac{1}{n \ln n (\ln \ln n)^2}, \dots$ of ever more slowly converging series corresponds to a sequence of ever more efficient prefix codes for the integers.

Comment: This is what I scroll through stackexchange for!

Answer (score 0):

This is a particular case of a *Bertrand's series*: $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac1{n^\alpha\log^\beta n}$.

This series converges if and only if

- $\alpha>1$ or
- $\alpha=1$  and $\beta>1$.

This is easily proved by comparison to a *Riemann series* for the first case  and by the *integral test* for the second case.